# PHP - upload de uma imagem

Tags: php, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho o seguinte codigo para fazer o upload de uma imagem:

```
var_dump ( $_FILES );

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["name"] );
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo ( $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

if (isset ( $_POST ["submit"] )) {
    $check = getimagesize ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"] );
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check ["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

mas no entanto o seguinte erro aparece quando carrego fazer o upload da imagem:
array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "css3.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php8UjGak" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(21455) } } File is an image - image/jpeg.

Comment: Isso aí não é erro, é saída do `var_dump()`

Comment: rray o que devo fazer entao?

Comment: É só remover o `var_dump()`

Comment: rray removi e deu certo, mas eu clico "escolher ficheiro" escolho a foto e depois clico upload, so que eu quero apenas que o aparece o ficheiro como tendo sido uploaded, no entanto isso não acontece aparece uma pagina em branco com a informação do echo. tem como voce me ajudar pf?obrigado, pf veja a imagem, acabei de adicionar

Comment: Na hora de escrever a mensagem mande o html formatado, aí vc joga a mensagem dentro de uma div com as classes de formatação.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que parece seu código deu certo, ele checou que é uma imagem. O que apareceu para você foi a saida do var_dump ( $_FILES );

No lugar do echo: "File is an image - " . $check ["mime"] . ".";
Você deve escrever seu código que define o que fará com essa imagem (normalmente mover para um diretório permanente).

Comment: Marlon, isso eu ja tenho feito: $Image = $conn->real_escape_string ( file_get_contents ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"]));